# PHP: Receiving PDF file via POST

Tags: php

I use a program called Nitro PDF to design PDFs, it has an option to create forms with submit buttons that submit to a URL. I tried to make a php script that would receive the PDF file and write it to disk but I can't figure out how to make this happen because normally you have to specify a name on $_FILES to receive it like "fileToUpload". Here is what it is sending to the server and then it starts sending the actual file:

```
POST /pdf.php HTTP/1.1..
Accept: */*..
Content-Type: application/pdf..
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;Windows NT 5.1)..
Host: 192.168.3.212..
Content-Length: 481677..
Connection: Keep-Alive..
Cache-Control: no-cache....
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not being posted as a form, the PDF is being put directly into the POST data, which you can read with `php://input`.

```
<?php
copy("php://input", "filename.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that created a file called filename.pdf but it's a 0 byte file

Comment: I'm not sure why. I just tested this with a manual POST request on my server and it worked.